# Properties files location in Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, properties, classpath

Is it safe to store `.properties` in `WEB-INF/classes`? Can anybody see its content via browser?

Comment: Files in WEB-INF/classes will be safe.  No users have access to it.

Comment: Why would you want to save .properties there?

Comment: Why not? Is there better place to save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WEB-INF` is not directly accessible from a browser, so most normal browser activity should not find it.

However, if the server does not restrict navigation by .. (parent of), many things on the server may become visible that were never meant to be.  (Yes, that is improper implementation, but humans are involved.)

Comment: Sounds creepy. Is there better way to store `.properties`?

Comment: for me its the best way, we already store our `.properties` in the `WEB-INF` and to be specific we store them in `WEB-INF\props\something.properties`